# osmdroid trigger tap on mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I am develpoing a map application with OpenStreetMaps. I am trying to generate a tap on a point from a `org.osmdroid.views.MapView` like can be done in Google Maps for Android:

```
HelloItemizedOverlay o = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable,getApplicationContext());
o.onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView);
```

So far I haven't found an equivalent solution.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that what I wanted to do was triggering a call to my implementation of onItemSingleTapUp on a specified item, so i did it:

```
this.onItemSingleTapUp(0, itemizedoverlay.getItem(0));
```